# Android como hacer para que no cierre la sesion del usuario cuando se elimina la app del segundo plano

Tags: android, google+

¿Como puedo lograr que cuando el usuario minimiza la aplicacion con el boton home o back y despues la elimina de las app funcionando en segundo plano no se cierre la sesion?

Resulta que se inicia  sesion correctamente con Google+, pero si el usuario fuera de la aplicacion, la elimina de la actividad de segundo plano, la sesion del usuario se cierra y cuando abre la app tiene que volver a iniciar sesion. Como puedo lograr que la sesion se mantenga iniciada?

Comment: Nicolas, ¿estas usando GoogleApiClient?

Comment: Si Elena estoy usando GoogleApiClient

Answer (score 3):

Si la eliminas es natural que cuando desees abrirla inicie de nuevo.

Esto sucede tambien si abres varias aplicaciones (prueba esto para que compruebes lo que comento) y estas requieren de memoria, el sistema operativo requiere esta memoria y aunque se encuentre en segundo plano, si intentas abrirla, esta iniciara nuevamente.

Si no deseeas que tu aplicación inicie por ejemplo desde un Splash Screen, deberas implementar que guarde ciertos datos que permitan inicie la sesión desde un inicio, aunque esto no sería del todo cierto ya que iniciaría nuevamente la Activity e incluso se ejecutaría el metodo `onCreate()`.